# How many ways can a cube fit into a sphere through its vertices?

Tags: geometry, spheres, spherical-geometry

I mean, we know that every cube has 8 vertices. Now imagine a sphere with a fixed radius. Cubes can have arbitrary sides, one way is this.  that there are no vertices on the sphere and the entire cube is inside the sphere, the other case is that the cube has only one vertex on the points of the sphere and the other 7 are inside the sphere.
Now comment on the rest of the states, i.e. 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8 vertices on the points of the sphere.
Comment which ones are impossible?
My idea is that states 3, 5, 6, and 7 are impossible
Of course, it is difficult to explain because each of them has different states, for example, three vertices is impossible because either all three must be in the same plane, in which case a rectangular sphere will not be formed in the circular cross-section, or with two vertices in the same plane.  be in another plane, which is also impossible because if two vertices are in the plane, it will eventually lead to 4 vertices on the points of the sphere.

Comment: It is not hard to show if 3 vertices of a face of the cube lies on the sphere, so does the 4-th vertex. Using this, one can show that $5,6,7$ are impossible. No idea about the case for $3$.

Comment: I upvoted initially, and voted to re-open. Even without context, this is an interesting question (to me, anyway). E.g., I can convince myself on vague intuitive grounds that only $1,2,4$ or $8$ vertices can be on the sphere... but I do not have an easy way to prove it. E.g., I'd be interested to see @achillehui's argument. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett for $n = 3,5,6,7$, there are not that many topological distinct ways to assign what vertices to lie on the sphere. following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOGKV.jpg) illustrates the topological distinct way of assigning the contact vertices and the light blue rhombus tell you the "faces" you can apply my argument to force the non-assigned vertices to lie on the sphere. As you can see, all $n=5,6,7$ are ruled out. So does most of the $n = 3$ configuration. The only one missing is the $V_{3c}$ configuration which need a separate argument.

Comment: Thank you to all those who expressed their opinions, but I must say that the V3c mode will also be impossible because the two vertices located on the same plane are on the square diameter.  The cross-sectional area of ​​a sphere should be placed in such a way that the two vertices of the square that are on its diameter are on the points of the circle and the other two fall inside the circle. This is impossible.